# Extract a json file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to write a script that takes a json file [pizza-train.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvyadaing4hsf97/pizza-train.json?dl=0) and extracts the *request_text* field from each dictionary in the list. But im getting an error when running the below code:

**Code:**

```
import json

json1_file = open("pizza-train.json", 'r')
json1_str = json1_file.read()

json1_data = json.loads(json1_str)

print(json1_data)
```

**Error:**

File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 58765-58767: character maps to

I've tried different solutions, such as: `encoding="UTF-8"` `.encode('utf-8')`

Can anyone explain my why it wont print the **json1_data** ?

Comment: Provide full stacktrace, please. Do you get this error on ```print(json1_data)``` line? If yes, then you can't print non-Windows1252 chars in your console since this is your console charset.

Comment: I got the error at that line. How would one change hes console charset?

Comment: show answer: use ``chcp``. Long answer is below

Answer (score 0):

Your data has some characters (at positions  58765-58767) that can't be represented with your charset (Windows1252). You should switch your console to charset that supports it (`chcp` command in windows).

Here is example:

I have file:

```
# coding=utf-8
print(u"русский текст") # This is russian text (cyrilic chars)
```

File is UTF8 itself, so Python knows that letter "й" is cyrillic letter.

But I have code page CP1252 that has no such letter (since it has only latin-based chars).

```
>chcp
Active code page: 1252

>python.exe foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(u"Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ‚")
  File "c:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position     0-6: character maps to <undefined>
```

I now change my codepage to one, that has letter "й" and other:

```
>chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

>c:\Python27\python.exe foo.py
русский текст
```

I can use 866 (which is DOS cyr codepage as well)